# Tensorflow: Export graph with remove_training_nodes gives error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to export a graph but when I use `graph_util.remove_training_nodes` I receive the following error:

```
ValueError: graph_def is invalid at node 'map/while/decode_image/Substr/pos': More inputs specified ('map/while/Switch:1') than the op expects..
```

I think the problem is with `tf.map_fn` since remove_training_nodes removes nodes necessary for it. When I don't include `graph_util.remove_training_nodes` I don't receive the error but I need to add it to reduce the size of the model. My code is the following:

with tf.Session() as sess:

```
    # Run the init operation.
    sess.run(init_op)

    '''
    Pre-process the image
    '''
    image_bytes_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name=bytes_input_node_name)
    preped_images = tf.map_fn(preprocessing_operation, image_bytes_placeholder, dtype=tf.float32)
    input_placeholder = tf.identity(preped_images, name=array_input_node_name)          # Explicit name (we can't name the map_fn)

    ''' 
    Construct the network
    '''
    net = models.GoogleNet({'data': input_placeholder})
    net.load(model_data_path, sess) 

    '''
    Create Graph
    '''
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()

    '''
    Freeze
    '''
    output_node_names='loss'
    output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
                            sess,
                            input_graph_def,
                            output_node_names.split(",")
    )
    output_graph_def = graph_util.remove_training_nodes(output_graph_def)

    '''
    Quantize Graph
    '''
    input_names = ['image_bytes']
    output_names = ['loss']
    transforms = ['quantize_weights quantize_nodes strip_unused_nodes']
    transformed_graph_def = TransformGraph( output_graph_def, input_names,
                                            output_names, transforms)

    ''' Create export session '''
    graph_export = tf.Graph()
    with graph_export.as_default():
        tf.import_graph_def(output_graph_def, name='')

    sess_export = tf.Session(graph=graph_export)
```